# using a where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to filter based on a table hierarchical relationship. But getting the error below.

I am trying to filter based on the variable C in `c.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name == C`

Can anyone advise, here is my code

```
var model = from r in _context.Departments_SubCategory_Registration.Include(c => c.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name == C)
                where r.IsEnabled == true

                select r;
    return View(model);
```

and error message
`InvalidOperationException: Incorrect include argument: c => (c.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name == __C_0)`

update. I changed my code to this below and get no error, but yields no results

```
      [Route("/{C}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Product(String C)
    {

        return View(await _context.Departments_SubCategory_Registration.Include(c => c.Departments_Category_Registration)


        .Where (d => d.IsEnabled == true)

                     .Where(r => r.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name == C).ToListAsync());
```

Comment: updated my code above

Comment: I tried you code and it works well.Make sure that your database has the record whose IsEnabled is true and its Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name is C.Could you share your models to us?

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your contribution. I found the problem was that, though I had added FK to my model, I had not added the correct key name in the Departments_SubCategory_Registration model, unfortunately it did not give an error  at runtime. Its working now, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass condition to the `Include` method. It's supposed to accept the property only. Change it to `.Include(c => c.Departments_Category_Registration)` and move the match by name condition under `Where` clause.